# Web scraping/ using request in python

Tags: python

Every time I enter two addresses on the command line the addresses get squished together. Also I can't seem to get the page to download using requests. I'm sure it's a simple fix.

```
import webbrowser, sys, requests

address = ' '.join(sys.argv[1:])
SecondAddress = '  '.join(sys.argv[2:])
webbrowser.open("https://www.google.com/maps/place/"+address)
webbrowser.open("https://www.google.com/maps/dir/"+ address+"/"+SecondAddress)

RES = requests.get ('"https://www.google.com/maps/dir/"+address+"/"+SecondAddress')
output = open("directions.txt", 'wb')
for chunk in RES.iter_content(100000):
   output.write(chunk)
output.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing this:

```
address = ' '.join(sys.argv[1:])
SecondAddress = '  '.join(sys.argv[2:])
```

Do this:

```
address = ' '.join(sys.argv[1])
SecondAddress = '  '.join(sys.argv[2])
```

Also you are not able to download the page using requests because you are not passing an url, you are passing this string:
'https://www.google.com/maps/dir/+address+/+SecondAddress'

Do this:

```
direction_url = "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/"+address+"/"+SecondAddress
RES = requests.get (direction_url)
```

Note: Pass both the addresses to the command line with '+' as a separator between each word like this:

```
python test.py airport+pune phoenix+mall+pune
```